# What is the behaviour of vector<T>().swap(x)?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I'm currently trying to re-implement the `vector` container. I just read on [this website](https://www32.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) that `vector<T>().swap(x);`, where `x` is a `vector` previously declared, could be used to clear and reallocate the `x` vector to 0.

I realized with this example that I'm not familiar with the use of a constructor (or what I think is a constructor).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::string T;

void    display(const std::vector<T>& input) {
    std::cout << "------START------" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        std::cout << input[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------END-------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "input size: " << input.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "input capacity: " <<input.capacity() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<T>   src(1, "Matthieu0");
    std::vector<T>   empty;

    src.push_back("Guillaume1");
    src.push_back("Paul2");
    src.push_back("Julien3");

    std::vector<T> tmp(src);

    std::cout << "------swap1------" << std::endl;
    display(empty);
    empty.swap(tmp);
    display(empty);

    std::cout << "------swap2------" << std::endl;
    display(src);
    std::vector<T>().swap(src);
    display(src);
    return 0;
}
```

So, I have no problem understanding `swap1` behavior, crystal clear. But I don't understand what is happening under the hood with `swap2` and how I could implement it.

Comment: what is `empty` ? Btw `using namespace std;` is bad, the code does not compile for me :https://godbolt.org/z/cx98fP3vj

Comment: That code constructs a vector with `vector<T>()` and then swaps it with `x`. So the claim that this sets the capacity of `x` to zero depends on the constructor `vector<T>()` creating a vector with capacity zero. This is not guaranteed to be true, but in practice probably is.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Just corrected. Thanks, I never use std except here cause I have my own namespace ft. Which is very convenient to test my own implementation and compare it with std. but nvm, I removed it.

Comment: The only difference between `swap1` and `swap2` is that in the first case the vector has a name `empty` and the second case it does not. Objects without names are called termporaries in C++. So the code `std::vector<T>().swap(src);` creates a temporary vector, swaps it's contents with `src` and then destroys it.

Comment: As a matter of interest you could research why the alternative `src.swap(std::vector<T>());` does not compile.

Comment: you can `using std::vector` or `using ft::vector;` thats harmless, while `using namespace std;` here triggered a confusing error message in other cases it can be worse

Comment: `typedef std::string T;` is an exercise in obfuscation. Bear in mind that in a typical code base, I'd imagine that 99% of time you read code rather than type it, it's best not to litter it with shortening `typedef`s merely to save typing time.

Comment: @john Thats, what I did, and I didn't actually understand why aha
Anyway, just realize the meaning of "swap", I though it was only empty that took the value of src and src didn't change. I m an idiot. Thanks :)

Comment: Please use cppreference from now on, which is a much better resource. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap . Not this "other" site.

Comment: @alfC: Absolutely. The claim in cplusplus.com that the effect on the capacity is different is pure conjecture - the standard does not state that. It would be compliant for an implementation to do something funky with that swap to clear idiom that preserves the capacity. I believe the compiler would be permitted to substitute for `clear`.

Comment: @alfC I hear you, tbh in my opinion cplusplus is easier to read, especially since I re implementing c++98 containers. But I ll try cppreference.

Comment: @UnDesSix: cplusplus might be easier to read, but you may as well read Peppa Pig as that contains fewer errors when it comes to C++.

Comment: @Bathsheba got it, I will be using  cppreference from now on.

Comment: @UnDesSix I also found cplusplus is easier to read, but if you persevere with cppreference it becomes more understandable, and there is a lot more information there.

Comment: @Bathsheba In the general case `swap()` will exchange the two blocks of storage used in the vector. So the capacity has to swap as well. `swap` is not allowed to resize the vector because: *Does not invoke any move, copy, or swap operations on individual elements*. In the case of swapping with an empty vector (data == nullptr) it could potentially allocate a new buffer with the old capacity. Assuming allocation is constant time (which it isn't always). But that would require a whole lot of special case code for something the vector is not required to do. Why ever would a STL ever do that?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: The question is really, why would it *not*? If you ever take the time to go over the g++ source, you'll see vast swathes given over to optimisation.

Comment: @Bathsheba You would also get problems defining the `end()` iterator because the trivial implemented iterator would differ for `data == nullptr` and `size == 0`, `capacity > 0` and `swap` does not invalidate the iterators. So you end up with `old.end()` and `swapped.end()` being different. So more special cases so `end()` with `size == 0` is different form `size > 0`.

Comment: @Bathsheba the optimized way is swapping the capacity between the two vectors, not preserving it.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: If you say so. You are on firmer ground with your iterator comments - that's something to think about. I can't recall if `swap` is required to keep iterators valid. There are a few functions, can't remember if `swap` is one of them.

Comment: @Bathsheba `swap` for a vector is `swap(data, other.data); swap(size, other.size); swap(capacity, other.capacity);` Any kind of code to preserve the vectors capacity would be less efficient and only work for the special case of one of the vectors being empty.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Some people like to consider a maliciously compliant implementation, that does exactly what you don't want it to with the latitude the standard permits, as part of risk-assessing their code.

Comment: @Caleth You can consider it. My argument goes more towards it breaking the requirements (constant time) for swap and it being really silly because you are shooting yourself in the knee doing it.

Answer (score 3):

> But I don't understand what is happening under the hood with swap2

When you wrote

```
//-vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------------->a temporary std::vector
   std::vector<T>().swap(src);  //this calls swap on the temporary(unnamed) std::vector
```

In the above statement you're calling `std::vector::swap` on the **temporary(*unnamed*)** `std::vector` created from the expression `std::vector<T>()`.

This is similar to the swap1 that you did with the exception that in swap1 you were calling `std::vector::swap` on a named object `empty` but here you're calling it on the temporary object.

Answer (score 2):

Many developers want to release memory occupied by a vector after `std::vector::resize(0)`.
It can be done since C++11 by calling  [std::vector::shrink_to_fit()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit). There is no such method until C++11, in  C++98, and developers use such a trick:

1. Create an empty vector.
2. Swap contents of vectors.
3. Destroy the vector created on the step 1.

For performing the step 3 as much earlier as possible, the limited scope block { ... } is used.

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::cout << v.size(); << std::end; // prints 10
{
  std::vector<int> tmp;
  std::cout << tmp.size(); << std::end; // prints 0
  v.swap(tmp);
  std::cout << tmp.size(); << std::end; // prints 10
}
std::cout << v.size(); << std::end; // prints 0
```

It can be shorter if an unnamed temporary vector generated by a compiler is used. The life time of an unnamed temporary variable is well known:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::cout << v.size(); << std::end; // prints 10
v.swap(std::vector<int>());
std::cout << v.size(); << std::end; // prints 0
```

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::cout << v.size(); << std::end; // prints 10
std::vector<int>().swap(v);
std::cout << v.size(); << std::end; // prints 0
```

It can be still used since C++11 for making

```
v.resize(0);
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

shorter and to guarantee freeing memory:

```
v.swap({});
```